Identify and describe the surface described by the equation: φ = c where π/2 < c < π.
In this context, φ refers to the polar angle between the z-axis and the radial line ρ as described by the spherical coordinate system with the following equations:
x=ρcos(θ)sin(φ)
y=ρsin(θ)sin(φ)
z=ρcos(φ).
If φ = π/2, the equation describes all possible values of ρ and θ that are co-planar with the xy-axis, so it would just describe the plane z = 0. Applying the same logic to the range π/2 < c < π, the original equation would describe every possible value that is below the xy-axis, so the original equation would be the same as saying z<0.
Edit: from the comment section. If c is a parameter then the equation describes the region below the plane z = 0 with the exclusion of the z-axis itself. If c is a constant which appears more likely due to the use of the word "surface" in the question, then the equation describes a cone with the tip at the origin and the base expanding indefinitely as z-approaches negative infinity

It really depends on how you are interpreting c: is c a parameter which changes , or is c a constant that simply lies within that range? Also, if you are interpreting it as a parameter, then the z axis would not be included in that region below the xy plane due to the strict inequality at $\pi$

I'm not too sure, it was from a test I took two years ago. So if c is a parameter, the equation would describe the region below z<0 with the exclusion of the z-axis itself. If c was a constant, it would describe a plane that would be below the plane z<0 and be parallel to it. If one wanted to calculate the equation of said plane in cartesian coordinates, they would set φ = c and use random values of ρ and θ to find three points in cartesian coordinates which could be used to evaluate the equation of a plane. Is this correct or not? thank you

The idea for the parameter was correct, however, if c were a constant then you would be in fact describing the equation of a cone below the z-axis, with angle at the apex ...(see if you can convince yourself why and what that angle is), so judging by the wording , it seems more likely that c is in fact a constant, as this is a "surface" so to say.

I think I see why, the polar angle would remain constant. As ρ increases the radial line would just keep extending to negative infinity. The plane idea wouldn't make sense because it could only describe a single value of z.

The problem says that the result is a surface, which implies that we should probably interpret $c$ as a given constant, and in that case the equation describes a single cone with the top at the origin pointing upward. The aperture angle is twice the distance between $c$ and the downward direction, i.e., $2(\pi-c).$
